# Couldn't load SIP module. Python support will be disabled: How to discard or remove some OS specific paths in Python path list when starting QGIS

Tags: qgis, python

I'm facing a (once again a QT5 related) issue when starting QGIS 3.26.2 (still present with QGIS 3.32.3-Lima) on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
Couldn't load SIP module.
Python support will be disabled.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/__init__.py", line 78, in 
    from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/PyQt/QtCore.py", line 24, in 
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so: undefined symbol: _ZdaPvm, version Qt_5


Python version:
3.10.4 (main,Jun 29 2022,12:14:53) [GCC 11.2.0]

QGIS version:
3.26.2-Buenos Aires 'Buenos Aires',feec3d3b12

Python path:
['/usr/share/qgis/python',
'/home/username/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python',
'/home/username/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins',
'/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins',
'/usr/lib/python310.zip',
'/usr/lib/python3.10',
'/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
'/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

which conducts me to a quite empty QGIS (every Python related stuff is not loaded).

How could I *force* QGIS to start with such Python path instead, in order to discard all *custom* packages installation:

```
Python path:
['/usr/share/qgis/python',
'/home/username/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python',
'/home/username/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins',
'/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins',
'/usr/lib/python310.zip',
'/usr/lib/python3.10',
'/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
#### two lines were removed here
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

?

Issue still present in QGIS 3.36 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Have you tried editing one of the startup script in the bin directory of your qgis installation ? I am not sure on linux but on windows there are several .bat files that set up all environnement variables

Comment: By doing so you will install Python packages under `/usr/lib` which is truly a bad idea because it will conflict with those installed by `apt` (I'm not even sure if it's possible or not). I'm thus using the `sudo -H` flag, which install them in `/usr/local/lib` instead, which is cool and I really need them here for some other softwares to be up-to-date. But indeed, being able to tell a software like QGIS to actually "exclude" that `/local/` folder from Python path would be interesting -- if not mandatory if such bugs are encountered. I'll try to figure out a way then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out that @Louis Cottereau was quite right with his comment:

> Have you tried editing one of the startup script in the bin directory of your qgis installation ? I am not sure on Linux but on windows there are several .bat files that set up all environment variables

So, here's what I did to finally solve this issue:

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ sudo nano -c qgis

########################################
#!/bin/sh

if dpkg -s qgis-plugin-grass >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    if [ "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" = "" ]; then
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/grass78/lib
    else
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/grass78/lib
    fi
fi

if dpkg -s qgis-oracle-provider >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    if [ "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" = "" ]; then
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
    else
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
    fi
fi

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# Added this unique following line:
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/share/qgis/python:${HOME}/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python:${HOME}/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins:/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins:/usr/lib/python310.zip:/usr/lib/python3.10:/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

exec $0.bin "$@"
########################################
```

And now QGIS can safely boot, ignoring all the Python packages I manually installed under `/usr/local/lib`, as if it was on a freshly installed machine.

That's nice, because there are other Python related softwares which I really want to be as up-to-date as possible, hence their custom installation within `/usr/local/lib` and their dependence to the latest `PyQt5` stuff for example.

With this solution, I can now keep the best of the two worlds.